# -fno-strict-aliasing as function attribute

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I have a function in which I'm type-punning for performance reasons. Basically, I have a 32-by-32 bit array stored as an array of 32 uint32s:

```
struct Tile {

    uint32_t d[32];

};
```

I then want to calculate the population (number of '1's) of the 28-by-28 'interior' of the 32-by-32 tile. The naive method would take 28 calls to the machine's **popcnt** instruction, one for each row. However, since **popcnt** can take a 64-bit argument, this can be reduced to 14 **popcnt** calls:

```
int countPopulation(Tile* sqt) __attribute__((optimize("-fno-strict-aliasing"))) {

    int pop = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < 30; i += 2) {
        const uint64_t v = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(sqt->d + i);
        pop += __builtin_popcountll(v & 0x3ffffffc3ffffffcull);
    }

    return pop;

}
```

If I don't include the attribute:

```
__attribute__((optimize("-fno-strict-aliasing")))
```

then g++ will consistently complain, for obvious reasons, about my type-punning:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         const uint64_t v = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(sqt->d + i);
```

On the other hand, if I do include the attribute, certain versions of g++ complain whereas others do not. Of the machines on which I've tried this, I get:

- g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4 **complains**
- g++-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 **does not complain**
- g++ (Debian 5.3.1-5) 5.3.1 20160101 **does not complain**

What's wrong with the Ubuntu flavour of g++ 4.8.4?

Comment: *which I'm type-punning for performance reasons* - a fallacy right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not type-pun. There is no reason for this. Instead properly use `memcpy()` to copy to and from your `int64_t` argument. Optimizer will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I generated the assembly code both with std::memcpy and with reinterpret_cast, and they're identical.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher, of course they are. You see, optimizers are written by developers for developers, not by some alien monsters who want to make our lifes unbearable :D

Comment: Anyone who suggested that in 1989 that a decent compilers should force programmers to use memcpy to avoid aliasing restrictions would have been laughed out of the room, if not shunned altogether.  The purpose of the Standard was to avoid requiring compilers to make pessimistic presumptions about aliasing in cases where there was no reason to expect pointers to alias--not to ignore cases where code takes the address of an object and uses the resulting pointer *via whatever type* to access the storage *before the next access to the object in question*.  Some compilers writers are obtuse...

Comment: ...but I see little reason to favor memcpy over using a suitable dummy "asm" directive before entry to the function (if it reads using alien pointers) and/or before it exits (if it writes using alien pointers) to serve as an aliasing barrier.  Memcpy is less of a dog than it used to be, but that doesn't mean it's always as fast as straightforward code, and it's certainly apt to be less legible.

Comment: @supercat, even if you disagree with standard, downvoting my answer is unjust. I didn't write it.

Comment: @SergeyA: The original question was asking how to get a clean and correct compile while using straightforward code to process data in chunked fashion.  On any decent compiler there are ways of putting aliasing barriers before and after a block of code; while the Standard fails to define such things. gcc has an `asm` extension that can serve the purpose. Is there any reason why doing a "memory-clobber" asm directive before the loop is better than memcpy within the loop?